# keeping X-axis length fixed in Qwt Plot

Tags: qt, qwt

I'm making an app for realtime data plotting from serial port using `Qt` & `Qwt`.I'm plotting data on `QwtPlot` object using `QwtPlotCurve`'s `setData(QVector<double>&,QVector<double>` method.Since I'm plotting large amounts of data,the x axis keeps on shrinking making the graph ugly after certain time.So I'm resetting the `QVector<double>` after plotting 500 points.It got better but I't still keeps shrinking till 500 points.I don't wan't that. I need the x-axis to be static.Any solution??

Here's part of code for reference.

```
    d = new QVector<double>();
    t = new QVector<double>();
    curve = new QwtPlotCurve("My Plot");
    curve->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
    curve->attach(ui->qwtPlot);
```

Plotting:

```
void MainWindow::plot(double val)
{
    if(d->size() < 500)
    {
      d->push_back(val);
      t->push_back(d->size());
    }
    else
    {
        d->clear();
        t->clear();
        d->push_back(val);
        t->push_back(d->size());

    }

    curve->setData(*t,*d);
    ui->qwtPlot->replot();
}
```

The `plot()` method gets triggered every time new data is available at the serial port.

Answer (score 1):

Disable autoscaling, see QwtPlot::setAxisScale()